# What is Clojure's equivalent of Scala's maxBy function?

Tags: clojure

Scala's [`TraversableOnce`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.TraversableOnce) has `maxBy`:

> `maxBy[B](f: (A) ⇒ B)(implicit cmp: Ordering[B]): A`
>
> Finds the first element which yields the largest value measured by function f.

Does Clojure have something similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest thing seems to be [`max-key`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/max-key):

> `(max-key k x)` `(max-key k x y)` `(max-key k x y & more)`
>
> Returns the `x` for which `(k x)`, a number, is greatest.

The name makes it sound like it only works with maps, but `k` can be any function.

The only thing missing is that `k` must return a number, whereas Scala's can handle anything with an `Ordering` instance.